# IplImage * in Objective C Methods

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I want to do frame comparison of video frames in openCV. 
Lets say frame #10 and frame #100 from a video file.
It works if I do it in the main video-capture loop. But now I want to move it to a dedicated method (which takes IplImages as input).

```
 // MAIN CAPTURE LOOP
 while(1) {

        cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 10);
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (!frame) break;
        cvShowImage("Window_1", frame);

        cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 100);
        nextFrame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (!nextFrame) break;

        cvShowImage("Window_2", nextFrame);  // THIS SHOWS ME TWO DIFFERENT FRAMES

        // PASS THE IMAGES TO THE NEW METHOD

        [self compareFrame: frame withFrame: nextFrame]);                       

        char c = cvWaitKey(5);  
        if(c==27) {
            NSLog(@"ESC pressed!");
            break;
        }
```

this is my method (simplified)

```
- (int) compareFrame: (IplImage*) firstFrame withFrame: (IplImage*) secondFrame
{

// THIS SHOWS ME ONLY THE firstFrame IN BOTH      
// WINDOWS?

cvShowImage("Window_1", firstFrame);
cvShowImage("Window_2", secondFrame); 

return 1;

}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you don't own the results of `cvQueryFrame`, the `cvCapture` structure does. If you want to do something with the results, you must first make a copy. The reason you see two different frames is because `cvShowImage` makes its own copy before displaying it. Once you get to the place where you call `[self compareFrame]`, frame and nextFrame are pointing to the same data.

Try this instead:

```
while (1) {
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 10);
    frame =cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (!frame) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't read frame 10");
        break;
    };

    frame = cvCloneImage(frame); //Make a copy of the frame     

    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 100);
    nextFrame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (!nextFrame) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't read frame 100");
        break;
    };

    nextFrame = cvCloneImage(nextFrame); //Make a copy of the frame

    // PASS THE IMAGES TO THE NEW METHOD
    [self compareFrame: frame withFrame: nextFrame];
    char c = cvWaitKey();

    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
    cvReleaseImage(&nextFrame);
    if(c==27) {
        NSLog(@"ESC pressed!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I now understand that. And It works now - but image copying seems like a rather cpu/memory intensive task. But It seems to be the only way to work with two images of the same video file...?

Comment: Yes, it's CPU/memory intensive. That's why `cvCapture` doesn't do it for every single frame, but instead reuses the same memory for subsequent frames. If you want to perform any operations on a frame you have no choice but to allocate memory where you can store it. If you are frequently working with just two frames you  can allocate the memory once and then copy the frames of interest into that memory.